# how to read from a locked file in Windows cmd script?

Tags: windows, cmd

I run a process that writes its pid to a file, Linux-style.
Specifically, I use Apache's [prunsrv](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html) to install a Java-based zookeeper program as a Windows service. `prunsrv` creates a pid file which I want to use to kill the process.

A `MINGW bash` shell **on the same windows machine**
can perfectly show the contents of the pid file. However when I try to read it in a cmd shell, either using `type` or `set /p a=<logs\zookeeper.pid` I get the "*The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process*" error. Is there a way to overcome that?

[image]

Comment: If the process has an exclusive lock on the file, then no, there's no way to overcome that.

Comment: To expand on that, it is possible (but very difficult) to overcome that limitation when writing a Win32 application.  From a batch file, no chance.  (It won't work from a bash script either, mind you, not if you're running Windows.)

Comment: ... but doesn't prunsrv allow you to stop the process by stopping the service?

Comment: @HarryJohnston I don't think the file is exclusively locked as I assume mingw bash does not do this special effort you mention.

Comment: That depends on the process that has the file locked. If your bash session is using the same process, then it makes sense you would be able to access the file. You can use a tool like [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) to see which the processes and file handles in use.

Comment: I would guess that `cat` uses a different share mode to `type`.  Most likely `cat` specifies `FILE_SHARE_DELETE` which `type` does not.  You could use Process Monitor (available from the MS web site) to confirm this.  Assuming this is the problem, I don't think any of Window's built-in commands are likely to work, but you could invoke MinGW's `cat` from `cmd.exe`.  Or perhaps use Powershell or something.

Comment: Oddly enough, `for /F` uses a different share mode which includes `FILE_SHARE_DELETE` but unfortunately it does *not* include `FILE_SHARE_WRITE` so is unlikely to work.  (Worth a try, though.)